# I can not connect through RPC port bitcoind

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-testnet

I have set up bitcoind, and I am able to run bitcoin-cli commands, I am also able to make request through RPC.

```
curl --user username:password --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id":"curltest", "method": "getblockchaininfo", "params": [] }' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' http://127.0.0.1:18332
```

It also works. But connecting through the public ip just return `Connection refused`.

```
curl --user username:password --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id":"curltest", "method": "getblockchaininfo", "params": [] }' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' http://public-ip:18332
```

It returns

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to external-ip port 18332: Connection refused
```

Here is what my bitcoin.config file looks like,

```
blocksonly=1
prune=1200
rpcauth=username:hash
rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0

[main]

[test]

[regtest]
```

The bitcoin node is runnning an ubuntu server and other applications/port allow external connections except all bitcoind RPC ports Is there away to fix this?

Comment: You should never expose bitcoind RPC to an untrusted network. It is NOT designed to be secure that way, even with a strong password!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RPC service only binds to the local interface by default.

Use rpcbind=<ip-addr> in your config if you want to change that.

However, be aware that exposing the rpc port publicly is a security risk.